# what url to put to show listings on my home page (javascript)

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, url

right now i am showing listings to my homepage if i put in the full url with "wwww.needsatrailer.com". I am trying to show the listings weather i put "www." or not. what would i put in my code for if.window.location?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    if(window.location == "https://www.needsatrailer.com/"){
                var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val(); $.ajax({
                    url: "{{ route('categories.ads') }}", method: "GET",
                    data: { _token:_token},
                    success: function(data){
                        $('#Listings').html(data);

                    }
                });

            }

        });

</script>
```

changing to this `if(window.location.href == "https://www.needsatrailer.com/")` worked perfect to solve the www or not. however now when i send the site link in a website like facebook it gives a long link like this `https://www.needsatrailer.com/?fbclid=IwAR2YlfDZda0frkWxFFhd5urA5szYSvSgt_1XdN3x0FGF75ewIBgiZkPy_Tg`
 which doesnt show the listings?

Comment: in place of window.location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [window.location.hostname](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/hostname) to find the domain of the current site. Change the if statement to

`if(window.location.hostname === "www.needsatrailer.com"){`

Comment: If this solves your issue, you can accept it by clicking the checkmark to the right of my answer.